# how to manage bitbucket project(repository) through FTP/SFTP

Tags: bitbucket

previously i was using sourceforge.net for my projects but now i am switching to bitbucket but I am not able to find ftp details to manage file,
Do bitbucket provide FTP/SFTP to manage files,if they where can get those details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitbucket do not offet FTP/SFTP support but you can use an service called [ftploy](http://ftploy.com)

Answer (score 1):

No. They do not.

They simply do not offer this.

Comment: Any other service which provide free project hosting with ftp support ?

Comment: A dedicated SFTP Host.

Answer (score -1):

**Install git, use that.**

Or if you are really sold on ftp and bitbucket then have a local ftp site and a git job which commits and pushes whenever files are changed. But you should really just use git, the learning curve isn't that tricky and it is a much more professional way to work.

- You can see a complete history of files.
- You can tag releases so you have more control over what goes in
- You can branch your code for various reasons.

Try it. You may just like it.

Comment: bitbucket uses git... -1 if I had the cred.

Comment: This comment is a nice explanation on how to use butbucket for someone who's not aware that there's git, but it isn't helpful for someone - such as the inquirer or myself - who wants or has to use FTP/SFTP instead of git.

Comment: For those who can't "install" a git client, theres portable versions available, i.e. for windows: https://git-scm.com/download/win